# How to pass data to servlet when clicking bootstrap modal button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, tomcat7

I am trying to create a web application but I am having some trouble in sending the data to servlet in tomcat server.

1. whenever i click on Admin button then a modal window comes up.
2. In modal window i will enter the year which i want to send to the servlet on clicking the send button in modal window.
3. But i am not able to connect server since i am using
   `$.post(....)` function in sublime.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link href="bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <h1 class="text-center">Admin portal</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myCreateDatabase">CreateDatabase</button>
    <div class="modal fade" id="myCreateDatabase" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="text-center">create database</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            Year: <input type="text" name="year" id="yearvalue"><br>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"> close</button>
            <button type="submit" id="submitForm" class="btn btn-default">Send</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#submitForm").click(function(event) {
        var name = $("#yearvalue").val();
        $.post('http://localhost:9280/dummy.html', function(data) {
          /*optional stuff to do after success */
          alert("i maskd");
        })
      });

      $("#myCreateDatabase").modal("hide");
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just FYI you're adding jQuery twice, and the second one will overwrite the jQuery UI integration. Change the scripts to jQuery 3.2.1, then jQuery UI, then bootstrap. Remove jQuery 1.9.1 completely.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to pass your form data like `name` as below:

`$.post('http://localhost:9280/dummy.html',{name:name}, function(data) { ..`

Reference: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/